# Feathers js - TypeError: app.get is not a function

Tags: node.js, feathersjs

I want to extract the host and port from config file(config/default.json etc) in winston-logger.js.

When I try to use app.get('host'), error occurs.

```
TypeError: app.get is not a function
```

config/default.json

```
{
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 3030,
  "public": "../public/",
  "paginate": {
    "default": 10,
    "max": 50
  },
}
```

winston-logger.js

```
// How to get app.settings in this file?

const app = require('./app');

console.log(app.get('host'), app.get('port'));//TypeError: app.get is not a function

const logger = expressWinston.logger({
  ...
})

module.exports = logger
```

app.js

```
const path = require('path');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const compress = require('compression');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const cors = require('cors');
const logger = require('./logger');
const winstonLogger = require('./winston-logger');

const feathers = require('@feathersjs/feathers');
const configuration = require('@feathersjs/configuration');
const express = require('@feathersjs/express');
const socketio = require('@feathersjs/socketio');


const middleware = require('./middleware');
const services = require('./services');
const appHooks = require('./app.hooks');
const channels = require('./channels');

const authentication = require('./authentication');

const sequelize = require('./sequelize');

const app = express(feathers());

// Load app configuration
app.configure(configuration());
// Enable security, CORS, compression, favicon and body parsing
app.use(helmet({
  contentSecurityPolicy: false
}));
app.use(cors());
app.use(compress());
app.use(express.json({ limit: '10mb' }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '10mb', extended: true }));
app.use(favicon(path.join(app.get('public'), 'favicon.ico')));
// Host the public folder
app.use('/', express.static(app.get('public')));

// Set-Up http request logger
app.use(winstonLogger)

// Set up Plugins and providers
app.configure(express.rest());
app.configure(socketio());

app.configure(sequelize);

// Configure other middleware (see `middleware/index.js`)
app.configure(middleware);
app.configure(authentication);
// Set up our services (see `services/index.js`)
app.configure(services);
// Set up event channels (see channels.js)
app.configure(channels);

// Configure a middleware for 404s and the error handler
app.use(express.notFound());
app.use(express.errorHandler({ logger }));

app.hooks(appHooks);

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: hey any answer? how you access the app in other file?